# Seemingly simple problem, no idea how to solve it. (in real analysis / multivariable calculus)

Tags: real-analysis, linear-algebra, multivariable-calculus, partial-differential-equations, partial-derivative

Let $A\in\mathbb{R}^d\times \mathbb{R}^d$ be a constant positive definite (so symmetric) matrix.

Say we have  some "well behaved function" $f:\mathbb{R}^d\to \mathbb{R}$ (Say Lipschitz and $C^1(\mathbb{R}^d)$). Denote $\nabla f$ its gradient. Is there a function $g:\mathbb{R}^d\to\mathbb{R}$ such that $$\nabla f(x)=A\nabla g(x)~~~?$$

(at least for almost every $x\in \mathbb{R}^d$).

$\textbf{More information :}$

The reason I ask is because I want to rewrite the PDE

$$ \partial_t u(t,x)=\text{div}\big(\nabla f(x)\big)+ \text{div}\big( A \nabla u(t,x) \big)~~~(1)$$

as

$$ \partial_t u(t,x)=\text{div}\big( A \nabla u(t,x) +A\nabla g(x)\big)~~~~~~~~~~(2)$$

Answer (score 2):

First of all, using the spectral theorem for symmetric matrices and performing an orthogonal transformation, we may assume that $A=D=diag(\lambda_1,...,\lambda_d)$. Then, taking the Fourier transform yields $\xi \hat{f}(\xi)=D\xi \hat{g}(\xi)$, $\xi\in \mathbb{R}^d$. From this equation it is easy to see that we must have $\lambda_1=...=\lambda_d$, i.e., $A=\lambda I$ for some constant $\lambda>0$. In this case, a solution trivially exists (set $g=f/\lambda$). So, a solution to your problem exists if and only if $A$ is a multiple of the identity matrix.

Comment: $\widehat{f}(\xi)$ and $\widehat{g}(\xi)$ are complex scalars, not vectors.

Comment: Thanks, I knew I was doing something so wrong. I forgot the definition of $\hat{\cdot}$ as an integral! Ok, now I see it : so for all $\xi$ we have $(\hat f(\xi)) \xi = (\hat{g}(\xi)) (D \xi)$ as *vectors*. The directions have to be the same , so in particular $D(\xi)$ has to be a scalar multiple of $\xi$ for all $\xi$, and then it follows that this scalar multiple has to be the same for all $\xi$. Great, I understand the proof completely now.

Comment: I was *hoping* for an approach that didn't involve Fourier analysis but rather went through more elementary methods, but I see that I don't recognize , among other things, how I would reconstruct $g$ from $\nabla g$ in a classical fashion. Indeed, the FT relates these via the Fourier coefficients, so I see the reason for its usage, but I'm still wondering if I can provide a more classical approach.